# How to print correlating index number in an array based on user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, user-input

I am new to coding, started learning Ruby arrays this week. I am a bit stuck on this problem that asks:

Create a program that asks a user to enter four different words, one at a time. Then, the computer will ask the user to choose a number between 0 and 3. The computer will then display the word corresponding to the correct number:

array = ["response_zero", "response_one", "response_two", "response_three"]

puts "Welcome! Enter 4 words, one at a time:"

4. times do

   response = gets.chomp

   end

puts "Now, guess a number between 0 and 3."

response = gets.chomp

** stuck right here on how to get the users entered number to print out the correlating array index. My professor hinted at only needing one line of code below the second response = gets.chomp, but haven't been able to figure it out for the past day.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried googling? This answer should be in the first hit. Also, you're constructing your array incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access an element in array you need to store the value of the input as Integer. So, you need to use the method **to_i**:

```
response = gets.chomp.to_i
```

By default, the **gets** method takes the user input as a String, so you need to explicitly convert it to Integer.

Now, you can easily access a particular element in the array:

```
puts "The word is #{array[response]}."
```

Where **array** is the name of the array and **response** is the number that the user entered.

Find more informations here:
[class Array](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html)
[to_i](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i)